# Why is my boolean variable messed up?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I declared my boolean variable, but it seems to be doing the opposite of what I want it to do. When I click on a button, it deletes itself, when the boolean variable was false. How could I fix it so that whenever I click on the 'delete' button is turns the 'deleteNow' variable to true? Because it seems that deleteNow is always true. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
public class deleteButton
{
    public boolean deleteNow = false;

    class ClickListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
             deleteNow = true;
        }
    }
    ActionListener deleteButtonClicked = new ClickListener();
    deleteButton.addActionListener(deleteButtonClicked);

    class ClickListenerTwo implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent f)
        {
            if (deleteNow = true)
            {
                JButton buttonThatWasClicked = (JButton) e.getSource();
                Container parent = buttonThatWasClicked.getParent();
                parent.remove(buttonThatWasClicked);
                parent.revalidate();
                parent.repaint();
            }
            else
            { 
                System.out.println("The button wasn't deleted");
            }
        } 
    }

}
```

Comment: Use `==` to compare, not `=` (which assignes values). With boolean you can drop the whole `= true` part.

Comment: Voting to close as typo for the above reason.

Comment: It's pseudo-code, not valid java. Might not be a 100% copy, and that he wrote == in the original.

Comment: Why is this pseudocode, this is a snippet from my program?

Comment: @oligofren Check OP thank comment on one of the off-topic answer... its typo... and its better to not answer. a comment did the trick 3 minutes before answers

Comment: @D.Maximov: there seems to be some missing statements. You cannot compile the above snippet. You are operating on deleteButton as an instance. `$ javac deleteButton.java
deleteButton.java:13: error: <identifier> expected
    deleteButton.addActionListener(deleteButtonClicked);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if (deleteNow = true)` needs to be changed to `if (deleteNow == true)`

`=` operator assigns the value `true` to the variable whereas `==` operator just performs the comparison.

Comment: I think it's just pseudocode.

Answer (score 1):

the following line is your error:

```
if (deleteNow = true)
```

needs to be

```
 if (deleteNow == true)
```

To make it work.

Instead of checking for equality, you do an assignment in your case, which will always result in the condition being true, so delete your button.

Answer (score 0):

Since your code is pseudocode and invalid java, my guess is that the error @Darshan Mehta mentions is not the real problem.

From your code the real problem is that you have two event listeners operating on the same state. Then the result will depend on whether the first event listener has changed the state of the button before the other has a chance to read its value. It seems as if the simple logic here is that the event listeners are called in the order added. A quickfix would then be to simply reverse the order of the event listeners.

A better approach would be to not have to different event listeners operating on the same state. Combine them into one if they are really meant to operate in tandem - as they do here. Then you can more easily control the flow of operations.